# Using multivariable calculus to prove inequalities and identities.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, contest-math

I’ve realized that onevariable calculus can be a great help in proving inequalities and identities, for example if we want to prove that $$(x+1)^2\ge 0, \quad \forall x\in \mathbb R_{\ge0}$$
we can just define a function $f(x)=(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1$, and we start by $x=0\implies f(0)=1\ge 0$ then we’ll prove that $f’(x)>0$ for $x\ge 0$. Of course this inequality is trivial because any number squared is $\ge 0$. but this is just an example of how we can use calculus to prove some inequalities.

Now if we have a $2$variables inequality like $$(x+y)^2\ge 0,\quad \forall x\in \mathbb R$$

Can we use multivariable calculus to prove it, or more generally Is multivariable calculus able to give us any kind of help in proving multivariable inequalities or identities?

Comment: The example you chose is not the best one, since you will usually want to start from $(x+y)^2\ge 0$ to prove more complicated inequalities, not the other way round. But of course the answer to your question is affirmative.

Comment: Maybe you will find more satisfactory answers if you ask for 'examples' of proving equalities based on the mv approach

Comment: If you know how to use multivariable calculus to find global extreme, that's essentially the same thing as using it to prove an Inequality.

Answer (score 0):

See [Lagrange Multipliers.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier)

They are useful for inequalities but usually aren't the nicest way to prove an inequality.

Comment: I already know it, but how can i use it to prove them?